# Find an explicit formula for the sequence whose first few terms are 1/3, 2/3, 2, 8, 40, 240...

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, pattern-recognition

I am trying to find the formula for this sequence:

$$1/3, 2/3, 2, 8, 40, 240...$$

I know I need to use a factorial in the formula, and then raise it to a power of something maybe? But from there I'm lost on what will work. I tried $n^3$, and a ton of other ones but nothing is working.

Comment: Try $n!/k$, for suitable $k$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, take out a factor of $\frac{1}{3}$.
The sequence is then:
$$1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, ...$$
Which is just $u_n=n!$.

So the required formula is:
$$u_n=\frac{n!}{3}$$

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly $\frac{N!}{3}$. You may like to go through [A002301](https://oeis.org/A002301).

Comment: Could also be $\frac{103}{120} n^5-\frac{437}{36} n^4 +\frac{1589}{24} n^3-\frac{6139}{36} n^2 + \frac{3059}{15} n -88$ ;)

Comment: @augurar: From the OP's post"I know I need to use a factorial in the formula".

Comment: It's unclear if that is part of the problem statement or just an assumption made by the OP.